# How to check if a row exist in the database using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, row

I want to have a condition that will perform some action when the row doesn't exist at all.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Tried `if (count($row) == 0)` and `if($stmt->rowCount() < 0)` but none of them works.

Comment: [`$stmt->rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) should be what you need, but checking if it is *less than* `0` won't help - it will be *equal to* `0` or *less than* `1`

Comment: @DaveRandom The docs state that not all drivers cause `SELECT` to give a `rowCount`. Apparently you should actually be using `columnCount`.

Comment: @arxanas A fair point, but frankly running two queries just to get the row count (as the manual suggests) is a sucky solution. Even `$rowCount = count($rows = $stmt->fetchAll())` is a better solution than that, I feel - and it will still result in `0` if there are no rows.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can just check the return value directly.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if( ! $row)
{
    echo 'nothing found';
}

/*
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Same here
if( ! $rows)
{
    echo 'nothing found';
}
*/
```

If you are asking about checking *without fetching* then simply have MySQL return a `1` (or use the `COUNT()` command).

```
$sql = 'SELECT 1 from table WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1';
//$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from table WHERE param = ?'; // for checking >1 records
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->fetchColumn()) echo 'found';
```

Comment: Your solution will work, but it is not true that `PDOStatement::fetch` returns an array; it returns the next result or `false` if there are no rows anymore. And that's why `$row` is false when there is an empty result set.

Comment: @matthias.p, thanks for the correction. I never use `fetch()` so my statement about an empty array was from `fetchAll()`

Comment: Thanks! that's what i was looking for. Since I knew the result was return in an array, I was thinking it could be the best way to check the variable instead of using a function or doing another sql query.

Comment: Can I use `rowCount()` instead of `fetchColumn()` in the `if` condition?

Comment: @Sajad the [manual says no](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php): "Returns the number of rows **affected** by the last SQL statement"

Comment: I don't know if current versions do something different.  But doing: $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
reads the first row.  So when I go to read rows later I'm missing the first row.

Answer (score 12):

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
```

should work fine, since the number of rows can't be less than zero in any event at all.

From the manual:

> For most databases, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a `SELECT` statement. Instead, use
>   `PDO::query()` to issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended `SELECT` statement, then use
>   `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

I would suggest reading up on that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: As arxanas already said, you should not use `rowCount` to detect the rows returned by a select statement.

Comment: If you're using MySQL it shouldn't be a problem, but otherwise you're completely correct.

Comment: oh then I was using the wrong sign. I thought if it does exist when its greater, I should just reverse it to less than 0 ! lol

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I use in my object classes:

```
function exists_by_id () {
    // check if object exists by id
    $stm = DB::$pdo->prepare('select count(*) from `table` where `column`=:column');
    $stm->bindParam(':column', $this->column);
    $stm->execute();
    $res = $stm->fetchColumn();

    if ($res > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting function.

Comment: return `(bool)$stm->fetchColumn();` to halve the size