# Insert if not exists PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this variable `$nombrecat` and I want to `INSERT` it into the table `categories` in the column `category`. But before that I want to check if already exists. This is my current code:

```
$nombrecat = $_POST['crearcat'];

$cmd = $connect -> prepare('INSERT INTO  `categories` (`category`) VALUES (:nombrecat)');
$cmd ->bindParam(':nombrecat',$nombrecat);

$cmd -> execute();
```

I want to check if  `$nombrecat` exists. If it does, do nothing, if it doesn't, execute my code above. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` - Google "insert if not exists mysql" and you'll find all sorts of answers.

Comment: Is `category` the primary key of the table? You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to perform the insert and ignore the duplicate key error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can't have a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Put an `UNIQUE` index on the `category` column and use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: @Barmar http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025332/

Comment: Sorry I don't understand all this "primary key" stuff. How does it work?

Comment: @pedritoalfonso Another way to do it without using any of the answers from the duplicate link the question was closed with, is to use a conditional statement on SELECT. If a row exists, then tell write your code to exit after the query. `if(condition){ do something } else { do something else }`. Here's an answer on Stack that you can base yourself on to check if a row exists http://stackoverflow.com/a/11974650/ - You can also Google "if row exists mysql pdo". Or as already stated, modify your column to have a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Yes I've done this, selected all from categories where category = $nombrecat, and stored it in a variable, and the use count() to check wheter it's 0 or 1, thank you all for answering!