# PHP - Laravel, MySQL, Select Exists query resulting variable and it's access

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have SQL query in Laravel as such:

```
$PDO = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
$sql = <<< SQLEND
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tpalautus where student_id = $id AND hnro=$num) ;
SQLEND;

$allsql = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$allsql->execute();
$result = $allsql->fetchAll((\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
dd($result);
```

dd shows me that:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#345 ▼
    +"EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tpalautus where student_id = 4 AND hnro=1)": 0
  }
]
```

My problem is that I wish to do if statement on this result, check if it is 0 or 1, how do I do this ?
I find it quite difficult to select this since objects key is SQL query statement.
For example $result[0]->KEY_HERE is not working with such a long string Query statement.

Can I somehow choose what I want as that Key name? Or any other way?

Comment: is there any reason you're not using Eloquent ORM and instead exposing a SQL injection vulnerability in your code?

Comment: its a school task, we did Eloquent first and then we have this exercise where you do SQL "manually".

Comment: I`m not sure I fully understand the expected result, but have you check the documentation for EXISTS https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

Comment: Also that might be a pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490188/55049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out alternative way, dont need to use EXISTS, just running a query with select

```
SELECT * FROM tpalautus where student_id = $id AND hnro=$num limit 1;
```

and then i check if count($result) > 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to convert the object into an array then flip the keys with their values for easy access

```php
$vars = get_object_vars($result[0]);
$exists = array_values($vars);
if ($exists[0]) {
  dd('true');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you! I didnt know I could flip like that. I also found alternative solution to not use exists and just run normal select with limit 1, and then check if count() > 0